# How to let custom window be closed if mainwindow is closed?

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I designed a custom messagebox for my WPF application with Expression Blend 4.
I copied the generated MyCustomBox.xaml into my project, changed the namespace to access it directly.

My problem is how I can make the mainwindow parent to my custombox?
If I close my mainwindow the custombox will still be shown. I would like to let the custombox be closed if the mainwindow is being closed.
My Custom MessageBox is a subclass of Window.

Thanks in advance for any hints :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Owner` of the popup window to the main window.

Comment: ah ok thank you it works! :)
on this way i can easily set the parent window via the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can call `Application.Shutdown` on main window close if closing main window should make application exit.